# MacOS drops internet connection when Safari is open, that affects my RDP sessions

Tags: network, safari

I frequently use RDP connections for work, and if Safari is opened i always get 0x407 error - that means that internet connection was dropped.
Tested with another browsers, like Chrome or Edge - and never get a single error.
Maybe somebody know how to resolve the problem and where to dig for the problem?

Also i checked the logs via Console and found that when Safari is opened - macos doing something with wifi(even if its disabled) and reconnects internet.

macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60)

RDP client - Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.9.5 (2179)

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the Handoff feature..?

Comment: @Josh I disabled everything, that can affect this.

Comment: Also explored a lot of console logs in macos, found out that Safari or Feedback appliction ask system to reconnect my usb hub, where my ethernet cable is located. Tried different hubs, expensive ones, and resuilt always the same.